# Meaning of "overcomes his encounters"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In an app's description, I found the following sentence:

> The game is full of happy moments when the main character **overcomes**
>   **his encounters** one by one.

Is something missing here? The phrase "overcomes his encounters" seems to be incomplete.

The main character is a lonely man who is looking for the love of his life. He meets many other characters some of whom give him heartbreaks.

Comment: I'd be prepared to bet any money your cited source isn't a native Anglophone, because few if any native speakers would use ***full of happy moments*** like that (but it does strike me as a stereotypical "translation" of what, for example, *Far Eastern* speakers might say). So I don't see much point in us trying to "explain" why such a person would talk about overcoming ***encounters*** (as opposed to more normal usages such as overcoming ***adversity, enemies***, etc.).

Comment: Adding to Fumble's comment above, "encounters" is being used in a neutral way, either positive or negative, as opposed to "adversity, enemies, etc" which are negative-only.

Comment: Given that the protagonist is looking for love, I assumed that _encounters_ referred to sexual/romantic encounters that either went badly (and must therefore be overcome) or were non-consenual.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a poor translation. While an encounter *can* be taken in many different ways, I would say it's more commonly neutral than either positive or negative.

A more likely translation is:

> The game is full of ***triumphant*** moments when the main character overcomes his ***obstacles*** one by one.

Although even that sounds a bit odd, the specific words I changed at least make it sound better.

There is nothing missing from *overcoming his obstacles*.